# Examining the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\Bigl(1-2\exp\Bigl(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}k\Bigr)\Bigr)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Problem:** Examine the convergence of the series$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\left(1-2\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}k\right)\right).$$
**Solution (part):** For the sequence $\alpha_n=(-1)^{n+1}\Big(1-2\exp\Big({\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\Big)\Big)\,,\; n\in\mathbb{N}\,,$ we have that

- $\alpha_{n}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Indeed
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
  \log2+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}&=\begin{cases}
  >0\,, &n\;{\text{even}}\\
  <0\,,&n\;{\text{odd}}
  \end{cases}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  \exp\big(\log2+\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)&=\begin{cases}
  >1\,, & n\;{\text{even}}\\
  <1\,,&n\;{\text{odd}}
  \end{cases}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  2\,\exp\big(\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)&=\begin{cases}
  >1\,, & n\;{\text{even}}\\
  <1\,,&n\;{\text{odd}}
  \end{cases}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\ 
  1-2\,\exp\big(\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)&=\begin{cases}
  <0\,, & n\;{\text{even}}\\
  >0\,,&n\;{\text{odd}}
  \end{cases}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\ 
  \alpha_n=(-1)^{n+1}\Big(1-2\exp\Big({\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\Big)\Big)&>0\,.
  \end{alignat*}
- $(\alpha_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing. ( This I wasn't able to prove fully.)
- $\lim(n\,\alpha_n)\neq0$. Indeed, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
  \log2+\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}&\stackrel{(*)}{>}\log\big(1+\tfrac{1}{20n}\big)>0\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  \exp\big(\log2+\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)&>\exp\big(\log\big(1+\tfrac{1}{20n}\big)\big)=1+\frac{1}{20n}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  -1+2\exp\big(\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)&>-1+1+\frac{1}{20n}=\frac{1}{20n}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  \alpha_{2n}=(-1)^{2n+1}\Big(1-2\exp\big(\textstyle{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}\big)\Big)&>\frac{1}{20n}\quad&&\Rightarrow\\
  \lim_{n\to+\infty}(2n\,\alpha_{2n})&\geqslant\lim_{n+\infty}2n\,\frac{1}{20n}=\frac{1}{10}\,.
  \end{alignat*}
  Because $\alpha_{n}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we conclude that $\lim(n\,\alpha_n)\neq0$.

By Abel's-Pringsheim's theorem the series diverges.

(*) Proof?

Ideas about the monotonicity of the sequence?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy $\lim|\alpha_n|\to|1-2\exp(-\log2)|=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integrating the geometric series with remainder, we obtain
$$
 - \log 2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{k}}  + ( - 1)^{n + 1} \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n }}{{1 + x}}dx} .
$$
Now
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n }}{{1 + x}}dx} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - nt} }}{{e^t  + 1}}dt}  = \frac{1}{{2n}} + \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} \left( {\frac{1}{{e^t  + 1}} - \frac{1}{2}} \right)dt} \\ & = \frac{1}{{2n}} + \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} \mathcal{O}(t)dt}  = \frac{1}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{k}}  =  - \log 2 + \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).
$$
Consequently,
$$
2\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{k}} } \right) = 2\exp \left( { - \log 2} \right)\exp \left( {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right) = 1 + \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)
$$
and therefore
$$
( - 1)^{n + 1} \left( {1 - 2\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{k}} } \right)} \right) = \frac{1}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).
$$
Since the harmonic series diverges, your series is divergent.